# How to specify name for routes of a resource route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

My need is that if in case I changed the route

```
Route::resource('/admin/users','AdminUserscontroller');
```

TO:

```
Route::resource('/admin/admin_users','AdminUserscontroller');
```

I have to  change all the anchor tag link one by one,, How to avoid that?

MY anchor link as following

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="{{route('users.index')}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
<div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
```

Users

```
<div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 3rd parameter to resource method, which takes array, include key 'names' to overwrite the route names

```
Route::resource('/admin/admin_users', 'AdminUserscontroller', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'users.index',
        'store' => 'users.store',
        //other routes of this resource as required
    ]
]);
```